# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I got a error on image upload.

The path for the image to upload is:
`app/assets/images/uploads`

Error message is:

`Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /uploads)`

Please advise,

My error Log:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 178ms

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /uploads):
app/controllers/admin/impact_levels_controller.rb:21:in `create'
app/models/tenant.rb:36:in`scope_schema'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:167:in `scope_current_tenant'

My path in uploader file to create (image_uploader.rb):

def store_dir

```
"/uploads/#{model.tenant_id}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

end

Comment: you don't have the write permission for the `app/assets/images' directory. use sudo or provide the write permissions .

Comment: add your server logs please

Comment: this error says you don't have permissions to create the directory check permissions using 'ls -l <path_to_directory>'

Comment: and then use 'chmod' to change permissions

Comment: will it affect on production server?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx : this is the current permission for that folder

Comment: How are you uploading the image? Are you using any gem?

Comment: carrierwave is using